# JACKSON with JSON: map unrecognized fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to convert a JSON string into a Java object. The JSON will have a few known fields and some unknown ones. Here is an example:

```
public class MyJsonBean {
  private String abc;
  private String def;

  // getters and setters
}
```

And the JSON I want to parse:

```
{"abc":"value1","def":"value2","ghi":"value3","jkl":"value4"}
```

Only fixed fields are "abc" and "def". Other fields are variable. 
I'd like Jackson to parse the variable fields and put them into a list/map within the MyJsonBean class. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Using the `@JsonAnySetter` in the duplicate linked, you can `put` those values in `Map` or `add` to a  `List` as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **@JsonAnySetter** Called by json deserialization to store non-member elements of the json object. Stores the value in the otherAnnotations field.

Jackson can actually be made to work with such POJOs: here is one way to do it:

```
 public class MyJsonBean 
{
    // Two mandatory properties
    protected final String abc;
    protected final String def;

    // and then "other" stuff:
    protected Map<String,Object> other = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    // Could alternatively add setters, but since these are mandatory
    @JsonCreator
    public MyJsonBean (@JsonProperty("abc") String abc, @JsonProperty("def") String def)
    {
        this.abc = abc;
        this.def = def;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public Object get(String name) {
        return other.get(name);
    }

    // "any getter" needed for serialization    
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String,Object> any() {
        return other;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        other.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

And there we have it: serializes and deserializes nicely.

Share and enjoy... :)

Comment: exactly the answer I was looking for!! Thanks @Abdel :)